# How to display the ip address in ion auth

Tags: php, codeigniter, ion-auth

I know we can use the [user](http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/#user) method of ion auth to get user data.

```
$user = $this->ion_auth->user()->row();
echo $user->ip_address;
```

But this gives an output u�8/ .How can I retrieve the actual ip address like 127.0.0.1.

**UPDATE**

Just to help others.

With help from *h2ooooooo*,I found that ipaddress is passed through `bin2hex(inet_pton($ip))` and then saved in db. To retrieve it use

```
$user = $this->ion_auth->user()->row();
 echo inet_ntop($user->ip_address);
```

Comment: That should be returning the IP address of the user. Could you look into the database and see what is stored for the user.

Comment: @xbonez The database value is 75f1382f. The ip address is passed through a php function inet_pton($ip_address) and then saved in db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that the IP is stored using `inet_pton`?

This is the result if we simply convert every 2 characters into decimal:

```
<?php
    $ipPacked = '75f1382f';

    $ipSegments = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i += 2) {
        $ipSegments[] = hexdec($ipPacked[$i] . $ipPacked[$i + 1]);
    }

    $ipReal = implode('.', $ipSegments);

    var_dump($ipReal); //string(13) "117.241.56.47"
?>
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/nogeLPtq)

Is that your correct IP?

If it **is** `inet_pton` (which doesn't make sense as most of those are characters outside regular ASCII scopes) then you can simply use `inet_ntop` to get it back.

To convert an IP into this hex format, you can do the following:

```
<?php
    $ip = '117.241.56.47';
    $ipSegments = explode('.', $ip);
    $ipPacked = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
        $ipPacked .= sprintf("%02s", dechex((int)$ipSegments[$i]));
    }
    echo $ipPacked; //75f1382f
?>
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/T0HYXALS)

Comment: Thanks .But I am not able to convert ip address 117.241.56.47 to 75f1382f using inet_pton .

Comment: @Arunu I've added an example for you as to how to convert an IP back into the packed format.

Comment: Thanks.Now I understood what is really going on inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

So, prolly a good idea to look that function up:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.inet-pton.php

You'll see that inet-nton() decodes it - give that a try & see what you get